# Can you tell when i can see a good example of "drag and drop" a cell of wx.Grid?

Tags: python, wxpython

Can you tell when i can see a good example of "drag and drop" a cell of wx.Grid. I have a two wx.Grid's. I want to move the content (or another data) from cell of first Grid to cell of second Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this help you ?

```
http://wiki.wxpython.org/DragAndDrop
```